# 'Record Not Found Error' while building search field - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am trying to implement a search field and I am getting an error

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BenefitsController#index

Basically

My controller:

```
def index
  @benefits = Benefit.search(params[:search]).all.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

My Model:

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
end
```

My View:

```
- form_tag benefits_path, :medthod => 'get' do
       %p= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
       %p= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil
```

Please let me know where my error is

Application Trace:

> app/models/benefit.rb:14:in `search'
>   app/controllers/benefits_controller.rb:6:in`index'

Comment: It'll be more helpful if you include the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better would be to use the `where` method which will return an empty array if no matches.

```
if search
  where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%")
else
  all
end
```

Comment: You could even do this one line `where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{search.try(:downcase)}%")` so if search is nil it will just do lower(name) LIKE '%%'. No need for the if/else